# Portable meta class between python2 and python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to get a python2 program working in python3, it has the following Meta class definition.  Which works just fine on Py2.  What's the "best" way to have this be compatible with both py2 and py3?

It's failing in the unit test where it does:

```
try:
    raise Actor.DoesNotExist
except Actor.DoesNotExist:
    pass
```

Failure is:

```
AttributeError: type object 'Actor' has no attribute 'DoesNotExist'
```

The base meta class definition is:

```
class MetaDocument(type):
    def __new__(meta,name,bases,dct):

        class DoesNotExist(BaseException):
            pass

        class MultipleDocumentsReturned(BaseException):
            pass
        dct['DoesNotExist'] = DoesNotExist
        dct['MultipleDocumentsReturned'] = MultipleDocumentsReturned
        class_type = type.__new__(meta, name, bases, dct)
        if not class_type in document_classes:
            if name == 'Document' and bases == (object,):
                pass
            else:
                document_classes.append(class_type)
        return class_type

class Document(object):
    __metaclass__ = MetaDocument
```

Comment: Why are you using `BaseException` instead of `Exception` here, btw? You rarely should use `BaseException`.

Comment: Simple answer - not my code, good point will fix when I fix the general case.

Comment: @eryksun: That's what Django does. Per-model `DoesNotExist` exceptions are derived from `ObjectDoesNotExist` which help make code that has to catch the exception for *specific* models only, much much clearer.

Comment: @eryksun: yup, but because the model carries the exception, you have it right at hand when using a model query: `try: user = User.get(username=username)`, `except User.DoesNotExist: return HttpResponseForbidden()`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could use the `MetaDocument()` metaclass as a factory to produce a class *replacing* your `Document` class, re-using the class attributes:

```
class Document(object):
    # various and sundry methods and attributes

body = vars(Document).copy()
body.pop('__dict__', None)
body.pop('__weakref__', None)

Document = MetaDocument(Document.__name__, Document.__bases__, body)
```

This doesn't require you to build the 3rd argument, the class body, manually.

You can turn this into a class decorator:

```
def with_metaclass(mcls):
    def decorator(cls):
        body = vars(cls).copy()
        # clean out class body
        body.pop('__dict__', None)
        body.pop('__weakref__', None)
        return mcls(cls.__name__, cls.__bases__, body)
    return decorator
```

then use as:

```
@with_metaclass(MetaDocument)
class Document(object):
    # various and sundry methods and attributes
```

Alternatively, use the [`six` library](http://pythonhosted.org/six/) for this:

```
@six.add_metaclass(MetaDocument)
class Document(object):
```

where the [`@six.add_metaclass()` decorator](http://pythonhosted.org/six/#six.add_metaclass) also takes care of any `__slots__` you may have defined; my simpler version above doesn't.

`six` also has a [`six.with_metaclass()` base-class factory](https://pythonhosted.org/six/#six.with_metaclass):

```
class Document(six.with_metaclass(MetaDocument)):
```

which injects an extra base class into the MRO.

Comment: Also written up as a [blog post](http://www.zopatista.com/python/2014/03/14/cross-python-metaclasses/).

Comment: In your first code, did you mean `Document` instead of `cls` coming out of nowhere?

Comment: Isn't it some kind of small hack? Is there any "major" performance drawback issue? (I'm especially looking at the first solution without the third part lib) My guess is that there isn't any other way around to make a metaclass compatible Py2 and Py3.

Comment: @JeromeJ: Python does almost exactly that; *call* the metaclass to produce the class object. In Python 3 there is also the body preparation step, but that's not supported in Python 2 so you don't have to care about that when producing a polyglot solution. The class is produced just once *anyway* so performance is hardly an issue.

Comment: Is it triggered when I extend the class? How to make sure this happens? _There is something I don't quite understand here,_ and so far, searches didn't answered my question. (I got a case where I got it working and one that doesn't but I don't get why so far)

Comment: Fixed: Turns out that `return type(name, bases, body)` instead of `return super(MetaClass, meta).__new__(meta, name, bases, body)` was the cause of the metaclass not carrying to the inherited classes. Credit to http://stackoverflow.com/users/918959/antti-haapala

Answer (score 1):

[`six`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/six) has a utility for this.

```
class Document(six.with_metaclass(MetaDocument, object)):
    # class definition, without the __metaclass__
```

The only side effect is that the class hierarchy changes from

```
>>> Document.__mro__
(<class 'test.Document'>, <type 'object'>)
```

to

```
>>> Document.__mro__
(<class 'test.Document'>, <class 'test.NewBase'>, <type 'object'>)
```

because `with_metaclass` actually returns a new class with the appropriate metaclass.